# How to block loading of a specific .js file?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I need to block uploading module.js file for site for my convenience. This file simply uploads by  tag. In the HTML code, it looks like this:

```
<script charset="utf-8" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1672056888038_9" src="https://exam.lood.so/lib/javascript.php/1671548766/mod/quiz/module.js" async=""></script>
```

I'm thinking of doing it in Tampermonkey.

Here I have a script that catches all requests in the
[xhr/fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXJnk.png),
but I need to abort the file in the "JS" tab.

```
(function() {
    let _open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
       _open.call(this, method, url, async=async, user=user, password=password)
    }
    let _send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
        let _onload  = this.onprogress;
        this.onload = function() {
            console.log(this.responseURL)
            if (this.responseURL == "my_url") {
                console.log("gotcha here!")
            }
            if (_onload != null) {
                _onload.call(this)
            }
        }
        _send.call(this, data)
    }
})();
```

Blocking in devtools is not solution because since each time to block this request, you need to go here.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the script tag ?

Comment: I tried It doesn't help.

Comment: So this is a third-party page you're trying to access?

Comment: If you comment/remove the script from HTML, it is impossible for the browser to load this specific script

Comment: @Johan In general, yes, but the page can be cached too.

Comment: No, I tried to delete a tag in tampermonkey and this tag was no longer there, but the request to the server was sent and accordingly the script worked.

Comment: The only thing that helped was the request block in devtools chrome, but it is not practical

Comment: I guess the task is more or less impossible. Once a script is loaded and parsed, there's no way to remove it from the memory. Also, it's not possible to block the loading from the userscript, as the script element doesn't exist before the script is loaded and parsed. What's wrong with your monkeypathced `open` method? When set before the script to block is loaded, it should work fine.

Comment: @Teemu As I wrote above it sniff only xhr/fetch requests but not file which is uploading by <script> tag or css uploading. You can check it by yourself on any site. I don't know what is a difference but it is.

Comment: Yes, I (erranously) assumed the script you want to block sends XHR calls, and those calls are what you want to block. AFAIK you can't block a script from a third-party page, I could be wrong with this, though.

Comment: I don't see really difference between xhr and script uploading file they are both requests to server. So I guess it is possible to block them both in tampermonkey.

Comment: Those two are quite different. A script is loaded during the page is being parsed (by the browser), an XHR is done by JS, which of methods you can manipulate.

Comment: Ok, mb not monkeypath but other method will be work to deny working that js code, it doesn't matter for me.

Comment: If that's the only file you need from that domain you could edit your hosts file?

Comment: @NickSlash What do you mean "your hosts file". Do you know that it is third-party site, yeap, not mine?

Comment: Yes I do. Hosts file is used like a local DNS (sort of) and is often used to block websites and their contents (eg advert domains).

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/49118/105287